# Login WebService in android

Tags: java, android, web-services, mobile

I want login using web service. I have problem when clicking the login button there is no response, I linked the loginActivity with mainActivity through 
include `layout="@layout/login_interface"` 
Please help me to find the mistake I made. Look at my Login class below.

**login class**

```
EditText editText;
EditText editText1;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_interface);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id._username);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id._passsword);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.singin_butt);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            login(editText.getText().toString().trim(), editText1.getText().toString().trim());
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Sucess11", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

public void login(final String User_name, final String password) {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String URl = KeysJason.URL_LoginUser;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(response, "sss");
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity_.this, ProductList.class));
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(String.valueOf(error), "sss");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Faild", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> parms = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parms.put("username", User_name);
            parms.put("password", password);
            return parms;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Please take a look at my main activity code below.

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
                implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
      }
 }
```

Comment: can you provide us with the error you catch ?

Comment: There is no error  but not button response, I believed there is a logic error?

Comment: post your layout file

Comment: In [API](https://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/toolbox/StringRequest.html)  for `com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest` I could see that subclasses must implement `deliverResponse` and `parseNetworkResponse` methods. 
Is it class that you are using? If so please provide us this methods. If not please describe full classs name, with package

Comment: Could you see network activity? Does request is sent to the server? Does it reply? Does client device recevies this answer?